# Eclipse Oxygen does not show using directive in the Outline section

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

As shown in the screenshot from a valid C/C++ include file the using directive is not shown in the Outline section:

[image: myInt is missing]

How can I enable this?

My Eclipse version:

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>
> Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
>
> Build id: 20171218-0600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the construct circled in your screenshot is not a "using directive".

There are three syntactic constructs in C++ that start with the keyword `using`:

```
using namespace std;   // using directive
using std::vector;     // using declaration
using myint = int;     // alias declaration; new in C++11
```

(An alias declaration can also be templated, in which case it's often called a "template alias".)

Eclipse CDT does show using directives and using declarations in the outline view.

Alias declarations are new in C++11, and Eclipse CDT does not yet support showing them in the outline view. [Bug 509120](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509120) is on file
to track this.

Comment: +1 because I didn't find this bug and explains all. Each Eclipse version I tested - in total 4 - didn't show it. Even in the include file the `alias declaration name` [`myint`] is not shown in the code completion either.

Comment: @AlBundy: I'm curious about the missing code completion you mention. Could you give an example?

Comment: OK. In Oxygen the completion works. In an older Eclipse version it didn't work. Sorry for that confusion.